# Running Mocha tests from selenium builder in a browser

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, mocha.js, selenium-builder

How can I run tests in a browser?

I use selenium builder to remember steps then I export the `file.js` and run it in mocha (npm test). The test is successful, but I can not call a browser.

If I export the `file.java` and run it in eclipse, everything works fine, but in mocha I cannot call any browser.

I've put drivers (e.g. geckodriver for FF) in the given folder, installed selenium server via npm and so on, there are different settings in `file.js` for a browser, commands, etc. But the browser won't appear when I run tests in mocha. (I am using windows).

I can run the tests which are written by selenium builder (.json). Having started the selenium server previously in the command line; I can run tests (.json) via SeInterpreter (without selenium builder). But how can I call the browser and watch the steps, I've written before?

Here is the code example:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var wd = require('wd');
    chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    _ = require('underscore'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    uuid = require('uuid-js');
var VARS = {};

// This assumes that selenium is running at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/
var noop = function() {},
    b = wd.promiseChainRemote();

describe('Selenium Test Case', function() {

  this.timeout(60000);

  it('should execute test case without errors', function(done) {

    b.chain(function(err) {
      done(err);
    })
    .init({
      browserName: 'firefox'
    })
    .get("https://google.com")
    .elementById("lst-ib", function(err, el) {
      b.next('clear', el, function(err) {
        b.next('type', el, "приветик", noop);
      });
    })
    .elementById("lst-ib", function(err, el) {
      b.next('clear', el, function(err) {
        b.next('type', el, "приветик", noop);
      });
    })
    .elementByLinkText("Картинки", function(err, el) {
      b.next('clickElement', el, noop);
    })
    .close(function(err) {
      done(err);
    });

  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can export your test case as 'Node.JS - Selenium-WebDriver' via file->export(in selenium builder addon - after recording the script) and make sure to save it as 'somefile.js' (javascript).You can execute it as 'node filename.js' in command prompt and see it in action .Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice!! Everything works fine when I use it!! But when I try to export as 'Node.JS - Mocha', in this case it won't work for some reason! I cannot execute it as 'npm filename.js' in command prompt and see it in action for some reason!